# How can I force a "Save as" dialog?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is there a way to force a "Save As" dialog?

Currently if you click on the link you will see the content in the browser, but I need the "Save As" dialog to appear. The file is located on a external server.

I already tried:

```
$("#download_link").click(function() {
    document.execCommand('SaveAs','1','location');
});
```

Unfortunately that does not work.

**EDIT:**

Of course it would be fine if the file just gets downloaded if the user has this option activated in his browser. I just do not want him to get redirected to the site.

It would be also okay if there is a way to do this with PHP, but it looks like that I need to do it with readfile(), which I do not want due to the traffic.

**I need a solution which works for a file on a external server!**

A comment, to point some things out:

> Sorry that i need to ask you that, but are you serious? I just asked
>   how i can force a save as dialog, and you come up with "illegal",
>   "obfuscation" etc? I mentioned it multiple times that the only reason
>   why i want to do that is to avoid that the desired file get's played
>   directly in the browser. This is nothing illegal, not either something
>   what i want to hide. I have also no clue why this question gets marked
>   as off topic.

Comment: you can't (cross-browser, at least)

Comment: _None_ of the related questions (see the sidebar) has helped you?

Comment: As @Doorknob pointed out, the answer is no.  Some users will have all downloads automatically save to a specific location, without a browser prompt.  This is a user-level browser setting, and there is nothing you can do in JavaScript to force the dialog.

Comment: It would be fine if it get's downloaded automatically if the users have set up the browser for this. I just want that they do not get to the site.

Comment: As mentioned above the file is located on a external server.

Comment: Of course i did. It's mentioned in my question that the file is located on a external server. Never mind.

Comment: @Michael - **why** do you need to do the save in this way?

Comment: Do you have any other way?

Comment: i have to say this sounds moralistic ambivalent, maybe even legal dubious...you will pretend that a file from a different source is originating from your server...technical: as long as you try to do this in the browser, the browser **will** have the information that the file is from a different origin and a tech savy user will have means to detect this. Your only solution would be to use your server as proxy, so either you will have to deal with traffic or with not 100% obfuscation

Comment: Sorry that i need to ask you that, but are you serious? I just asked how i can force a save as dialog, and you come up with "illegal", "obfuscation" etc? I mentioned it multiple times that the only reason why i want to do that is to avoid that the desired file get's played directly in the browser. This is nothing illegal, not either something what i want to hide. I have also no clue why this question gets marked as off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Using HTML5 you can simply use the download attribute.

Ex: `<a href="myfile.pdf" download="myfile.pdf">Download Your Expense Report</a>`

Comment: Thanks, but it doe snot work on Firefox?

Comment: Sure it does. Firefox 20+.

Comment: I use 25.0 but nothing happens. On chrome it works fine.

Comment: Works fine here using FF25.

Comment: Well that's weird.. No idea why it does not work for me.. I need a stable solution :/

Comment: According to the [MDN docs on `<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download), FF only honours the `download` attribute for same origin requests, which would explain why it doesn't work (assuming "external server" means cross origin request).

Comment: It does not work , I replace the src with example.com/1.png it directs me to the preview of the image rather than prompt for direct download or save as dialog

Answer (score 1):

If the file is displayed in the browser as text or get downloaded as a file depends on the header that get send with the file.
For example this is the header for a excelfile:

```
 header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"myfilename.xlsx\"");
 header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
```

(the Excelfile is generated with php, without this header I would see the hole file in the browser as text)

The important thing is the Content-Type.

### Edit: without readfile()

As you say in your question you don't want to use PHP cause of readfile() you can also set the header with htaccess.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:txt)$">
 ForceType application/octet-stream
</FilesMatch>
```

application/octet-stream = something binary (so it get allways downlaoded).
You will have to rewrite the FilesMatch to match your files

Comment: That works with a external url? I mean the htaccess solution?

Comment: it wouldn't, the request wouldn't be routed over your server

Comment: Then he did not read my question. I need it for a external url.

Comment: @Michael If you don't have access to the server and if the file is just displayed when u call the link to it then you have bad cards. How big are the files? you can force a download with Javascript: `location.href = "data:application/octet-stream," + encodeURIComponent("hello world")` you could replace "hello world" with the content of the files. The bad thing is, you cant set a file name.