# C# Download Image from Url to NO specific folder

Tags: c#, image, sharepoint, download

I need to download images from my SharePoint site.
I have a button which gets the URL of the image above it, to download it.
But I want that the Users can choose, where he wants to store the images.
So how can i download an image from the Url without setting a specific folder?

I just know methods like:
webClient.Downloadfile -> Needs a Path to save
Image.Save -> Needs a Path to save

I am searching for something like you right click an image in your browser and it says "Save image as" thats exactly what i want

My code where i tried to choose the download folder (I get a 403 FORBIDDEN error):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();            
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("*******", "******", "**");
        client.DownloadFile(new Uri(string.Concat("http://******/apps/bilddb/PrivateStore/", item.FileName)), String.Concat(@"C:\Users\", System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, @"\Downloads"));
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are the issues you ancountered? This is no we-will-write-your-code-for-you-service (really should have this as a shortcut). You should show some effort by yourself.

Comment: Is there not just a method which I dont know? I am searching for it

Comment: How should a method similar to `webClient.DownloadFile` magically know *how* to ask for your path? The point of programming is - well - to program what you want to achieve and not to expect it happen magically. I will try to write an answer containing some hints, though...

Comment: Okay I will make it easier.
If you right click an Image in your browser, you can choose "Save image as"
Thats what I want because then it asks for the Path to save at

Comment: Where are you running your code? Is the code you're trying to write server side code or client side?

Comment: I am running my code server side

Comment: And how do you use ´webClient.DownloadFile`? I think I did not really get your use-case completely. `WebClient` is to be used client side. When you're running `webClient.DownloadFile` server-side you'll download that file to your server (presumably *from* your server, too).

Comment: I will show you my Code

Comment: Okay, let me paraphrase what you want: You are running sharepoint, which users are accessing via a browser. There you have a button and on click you dynamically want to generate an URL from which users can download a file. If I got it right, you should somehow redirect the user to the file whose name you created and depending on the type the the browser will save or show it. It has nothing to do with `webClient.DownloadFile` (which is misplaced here), but with the browser.

Comment: Yes but if I redirect the user, it will just open the image.
I want that browser funktion "Rightklick -> "Save image as"" in a Button under the Image

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039533/how-can-i-force-a-save-as-dialog).